# Отправка формы на сервер django

Tags: reactjs, форма

Не понимаю как отправить данные из формы react на сервер, если в форме присутствуют поля input и select

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Содержимое формы

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

function Aparts(){
    


    return(   
        <form id="form1" className="row g-3 position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style={{borderWidth:'thick',borderColor: 'black', borderStyle: 'solid',borderRadius:'10px', backgroundColor:'white'}} action='/apply/' method='PUT'>
            <h3 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>Введите информацию о квартире</h3>

            {/*поле адрес */}

            <div class="col-12">
                <input name='address' type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Адрес" required />
            </div>

            {/*поле метро*/}
            <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="floatingSelect">
                    <option selected>Авиамоторная</option> <option selected>Академическая</option>
                      
                </select>
                <label for="floatingSelect">Метро</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* поле этаж */}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name='floor' type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Этаж" required />
            </div>

             {/* поле этажи в доме */}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name='floor_amount' type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Количество этажей в доме" required />
            </div>

            {/* количество комнат*/}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name='rooms' type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Количество комнат" required />
            </div>

             {/* квадратные метры */}
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input name='metres' type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Квадратные метры" required />
            </div>

            {/* размер кухни */}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input name='kitchen' type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Размер кухни" required />
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-floating">
            <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelect" aria-label="Floating label select example">
                <option selected>Косметический</option>
                <option value="1">Евро</option>
                <option value="2">Дизайнерский</option>
                <option value="3">Требует ремонта</option>
            </select>
            <label for="floatingSelect">Ремонт</label>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div className="d-grid gap-2 mx-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"> Отправить </button>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            
        </form>
     )
    }
export default Aparts;
```

Comment: Так форма сама может отправить данные. Ей можно указать атрибуты `metchd`, `action` и данные пойдут куда нужно! Если отправлять без перезагрузки страницы - собрать все значения полей и отправить запрос на нужный адрес. Потом обработать ответ... Вот примеры таких "отправок" https://www.mousedc.ru/learning/593-post-dannye-fetch-javascript-formdata/

Comment: Опечатался в одном атрибуте... Правильно - `method`.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, но после отправки формы я просто перенаправляюсь на страницу с api с введенными из формы данными

Comment: Так ты отправила данные формы... В ответ можешь сразу получить файл. Или получить УРЛ по которому тот файл можно будет получить. Или я не так понял твой ответ?